# IIS redirect on link

Tags: iis

I am struggling with the following problem: A user enters a link like app.test.com/app1 or app.test.com/app2. The IIS is running on port 80 and app1 is running on port 9000 and app2 is running on port 9001.

I want that the app.test.com/app1 is being resolved as app.test.com:9001/app1 respectively app.test.com/app2 as app.test.com:9002/app2.

Is that possible within IIS? If yes, I would appreciate it a lot if someone can pinpoint me into the "solution direction".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [IIS rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to redirect the user.

Create an inbound rule for the site running on port 80, set the Match URL to the 'exact match' option and enter the URL as users would enter it (IE, 'app1', or 'app2'. This would be everything after the HTTP host/domain). Next, go to the actions section and set it to redirect, and finally enter the URL of the application you would like to direct them at (app.test.com:9001/app1, app.test.com:9002/app2, etc.). You also have options to append the query string data and to set the appropriate HTTP status code for the redirect.